# Should routed components have selectors in Angular?

Tags: angular

It appears that it is not mandatory to have selectors defined at all for the components that are not referenced by (included into the markup of) other components, i.e. those usually displayed by router (`<router-outlet>`).

I noticed that if you do give them selector tag, they appear with that tag in the generated HTML like this:

```
<app-root>
  <router-outlet>
    <app-dashboard>
      ...
```

But if you don't, the `ng-component` default is used:

```
<app-root>
  <router-outlet>
    <ng-component>
      ...
```

Notice that `ng-component` was inserted instead of `app-dashboard`.

**My question is**: is there any other difference whether you provide the selector for such (router-only) component? I guess not, but couldn't find authoritative reference.

And if there are no functional differences, what would be the preferred approach to use, i.e. what would better express intent / be more semantically correct: to have selectors defined or to omit them in such case?

Answer (score 3):

To get more semantic HTML for debugging, you can use a selector tag, but for other cases, less is more, so omitting tag seems to be preferable. This way it's clear for yourself and other developers that the component you are dealing with is an end-point of a router path

Comment: So the clear answer to this is that the selector declaration is OPTIONAL for purpose of HTML debugging.
Omitting it makes it clearer to the developers that it is a ROUTING item. I just spent the last 20 minutes trying to figure out what was going on with an app I'm in and am new to ROUTES.