# Applying host styles to child router outlets

Tags: angular, router-outlet, angular2viewencapsulation

I am working on an app which has a main view, and inside it renders several named child router outlets. The code is as follows:

app.component.html:

```html
<router-outlet />
```

app.routes.ts:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SlotsView, children: [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'slotA',
        component: RouterOutlet1,
      },{
        path: '',
        outlet: 'slotB',
        component: RouterOutlet2,
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

slots.view.html:

```html
This is a view with some child routes
<br>
<router-outlet name="slotA"></router-outlet>
<br>
<router-outlet name="slotB"></router-outlet>
```

RouterOutlet1:

- html:

```html
I am Router outlet 1
```

- less:

```css
:host{
  background-color: #f88;
}
```

- ts:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './router-outlet-1.router-outlet.html',
  styleUrls: ['./router-outlet-1.router-outlet.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  standalone: true
})
// eslint-disable-next-line  @angular-eslint/component-class-suffix
export class RouterOutlet1{
}
```

RouterOutlet2:

- html:

```html
I am Router outlet 2
```

- less:

```css
:host{
  background-color: #88f;
}
```

- ts:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './router-outlet-2.router-outlet.html',
  styleUrls: ['./router-outlet-2.router-outlet.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  standalone: true
})
// eslint-disable-next-line  @angular-eslint/component-class-suffix
export class RouterOutlet1{
}
```

Note that the difference between both router outlets is that router outlet 1 should have a reddish color (`#f88`), and router outlet 2 should have a bluish color (`#88f`).

This is what actually happens:

[image]

In DevTools I see that both host elements have the same attribute (`_nghost-ng-c4243086843`)
[image]

And that's why the same style is applied to both of them.

If I change the `encapsulation` on both router outlets to `ShadowDom`, the result is rendered correctly:

[image]

### The question:

Is this a bug in Angular which should be reported to the developers, or is there a good reason for Router outlet 1's styles to be applied to Router outlet 2?

I already did a bit of googling and haven't found such a bug report.

I tried changing the `encapsulation` mode.

- With `None` no styles are applied with the `:host` rule as explained here: [Is it possible to style using :host with Encapsulation.None in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090568/is-it-possible-to-style-using-host-with-encapsulation-none-in-angular)
- With `ShadowDom` it works correctly, but I don't want to use it unless it is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

after checking the replicated stackblitz from the user, the below change fixes the issue!

- Since the same `ng-component` is present for both router-outlets we are getting this issue, This definetly looks like a bug in angular, because each element should have their own encapsulation if they are from different outlets!
- To solve this issue, we need to use the `host styling` directly on the element so that even if the attributes match, the direct application of the styles ensures the colors are applied to the correct elements

snippet!

```
...
host: {
  ['style.backgroundColor']: '#f88',
},
...
```

---

outlet 1

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './router-outlet1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./router-outlet1.component.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  host: {
    ['style.backgroundColor']: '#f88',
  },
  standalone: true,
})
export class RouterOutlet1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

outlet 2

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './router-outlet2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./router-outlet2.component.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  host: {
    ['style.backgroundColor']: '#88f',
  },
  standalone: true,
})
export class RouterOutlet2Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xm8mze?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Frouter-outlet1%2Frouter-outlet1.component.ts,src%2Frouter-outlet2%2Frouter-outlet2.component.ts,src%2Fslots-view%2Fslots-view.component.ts,src%2Frouter-outlet2%2Frouter-outlet2.component.less,src%2Frouter-outlet1%2Frouter-outlet1.component.less)

---

Note: This output is coming from `ng-component` which is not even a proper component, you can just redirect the url to accomodate both the named router outlets and the components will get rendered instead of `ng-component`!

---

It looks like a bug but I don't think its replicable in the latest version of angular (17)

Here is a stackblitz that shows the issue not happening!

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sqprv2?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Frouter-outlet2%2Frouter-outlet2.component.ts,src%2Fslots-view%2Fslots-view.component.ts,src%2Frouter-outlet1%2Frouter-outlet1.component.ts)

[image]

---

To Solve this issue, you can add a `host class` on the component decorator, this will ensure the class gets applied on the correct host!

outlet 2

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-router-outlet2',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    I am Router outlet 2
  `,
  styles: `
    :host.outlet2 {
      background-color: #88f;
    }
  `,
  host: {
    '[class.outlet2]': 'true',
  },
  standalone: true,
})
export class RouterOutlet2Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

outlet 1

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-router-outlet1',
  template: `
    I am Router outlet 1
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styles: `
    :host.outlet1 {
      background-color: #f88;
    }
  `,
  host: {
    '[class.outlet1]': 'true',
  },
  standalone: true,
})
export class RouterOutlet1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-smg36p?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Frouter-outlet1%2Frouter-outlet1.component.ts)

Comment: Please include all code here on Stack Overflow as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this is special case, i usually dont, just this once!

Comment: @NarenMurali Thanks, this is very interesting.

I forked your example and replicated the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rhnecp

Comment: @NarenMurali I found that the only difference that is necessary to make it work is to add a `selector` to both components: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gs1pji

It didn't seem to me that selectors were necessary for components in router-outlets, which is also pointed out in several older answers on SE (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455129/should-routed-components-have-selectors-in-angular).

So I guess this could be called a bug in Angular.

Comment: @jgosar updated my answer, yes its a bug in angular, you should report it! also my workaround seems to work!

Comment: Can you update the answer to point out that the deciding factor in making it work was adding the `selector`? And also that the bug is reproducible in Angular 17.1, as can be seen in my StackBlitz?

Comment: @jgosar updated, nice find!

Comment: @jgosar do give green tick if this answer solved your issue!

Comment: I feel you're over-complex the problem. The problem is that the component have no selector. If you add a selector, simply you use in component.css `:host{background-color: #f88;}`? NOTE: My answer is when you want that the component store in an router-outlet have some .css, but if the .css is belong to the component simply use `styles:['{:host{...}}']`

Comment: @Eliseo why do you say there is no selector the issue is due to ng-component not having a unique attribute in view encapsulation, this is a bug right, angular should not reuse attributes and styles should be encapsulated

Comment: @NarenMurali, if you don't use a selector in your components, Angular by defect use `ng-component` as "tag", if you use a selector use the `selector` as "tag". When you use `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (the default option), Angular create a style in the way `[_nghost-ng-c252378840]{....}`, but Angular don't give a different "[_nghost-ng-c252378840] when you have the same "tag". This is the reason the .css is overlapped

Comment: I forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7jmhg5?file=src%2Frouter-outlet2%2Frouter-outlet2.component.ts,src%2Frouter-outlet1%2Frouter-outlet1.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts). See that if you remove the selector in both components, the .css is overlapped, (equal if you use the same selector). See also that if you change the path and in slotB is the RouterOutlet1Component, also  the `[ng-c44343]` is the same. In my opinion, it's not a "bug" is how works Angular.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the background-color of router-outlet name="slotA" and router-outlet name="slotB" you can use the [next-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator) (the `+`) in **global** style.css like:

```css
router-outlet[name="slotA"] + *{
  background-color:#88f;
}
router-outlet[name="slotB"] + *{
  background-color:#f88;
}
```

Comment: This would work for this example, but in our actual application I want to be able to use Router outlet 2 in different places, so its styles need to be self-contained.

Also the purpose of this layout is that different components can occupy SlotB based on the `Routes` config, so SlotB can't have any styles that are dependent on what is rendered inside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a summary of what I have learned and about the solutions here for posterity. Thanks to @naren-murali for helping solve the issue.

Here is a minimum example that replicates the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rhnecp

The proper fix was to add `selector`s to both components:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gs1pji

I reported this issue to the Angular team as well:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/54304

They pointed out that there was a warning in the console related to this:

```
NG0912: Component ID generation collision detected.
Components 'RouterOutlet1Component' and 'RouterOutlet2Component'
with selector 'ng-component' generated the same component ID.
To fix this, you can change the selector of one of those components
or add an extra host attribute to force a different ID.
Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0912
```

So the solution was in the warning message all along :)